# php strpos special characters

Tags: php

I'm using PHP Version 5.1.6

I have a string (session file) and need to extract a value from it, so i'm searching for a needle in the string but it returns false, I reduced the code to this:

```
$string = ';SERVER_NAME|s:17:"stackoverflow.com";REMOTE_ADDR|s:13:"69.59.196.211";';
$start = strpos($string, ';SERVER_NAME|s:"');
echo $start; // prints nothing because $start = false

$start = strpos($string, 'SERVER_NAME|s:');
echo $start; // prints 1;
```

As you noticed if I have the character ';' or the character '"' in the needle, the search returns false, I tryed to use chr() for all characters in the needle but had the same result, If I remove the ';' and the '"' from the string if finds the needle in the string.

How can I search special characters in a string using PHP ?

Comment: ';SERVER_NAME|s:17:"' !== ';SERVER_NAME|s:"' --- needle is not present in string

Comment: Though the right answer is still unserialize() and array search

Comment: unserialize() does not work with this format of string (if i serialize the string with serialize() the format is not the same as this), that was my first choise, but didn't succed in implementing it.

Comment: I stumbled upon this question, and I rememberd that I implemented bmorel's code that he posted as documentation comment at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-decode.php#56106 (it did not failed so far, but I just used it in that single project that is up and running till today).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are searching for `;SERVER_NAME|s:"` which clearly is not present in the haystack. I guess you meant to use `;SERVER_NAME|s:17:"` as the needle.

```
$start = strpos($string, ';SERVER_NAME|s:17:"');
echo $start; // prints 0
```

---

It was a typo that i missed, sorry problem solved.
  The correct code is:

```
$result = ';SERVER_NAME|s:17:"stackoverflow.com";REMOTE_ADDR|s:13:"69.59.196.211";';
$str_start = ';SERVER_NAME|s:';
$str_end = ':"';
$start = strpos($result, $str_start)+strlen($str_start);
$end = strpos($result, $str_end, $start);
$len = $end - $start;
$str_len = substr($result, $start, $len);
echo $server_name = substr($result, ($end + strlen($str_end)), $str_len);
```

and at the end it prints:
stackoverflow.com

So it works, thank you all for help !

Answer (score 1):

I'd  say you think it is false because the string's position might be `0` which evaluates to `FALSE` (assuming you are using a needle that is present in the string). You should always compare with `===`.

From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) (a big red warning box):

> **Warning**
>
> This function may return Boolean `FALSE`, but may also return a non-Boolean value which evaluates to `FALSE`, such as `0` or `""`. Please read the section on Booleans for more information. Use the `===` operator for testing the return value of this function.

It works perfectly for me with `"` . The first echo prints nothing because the substring `;SERVER_NAME|s:"` is indeed not contained in the original string.

Comment: the string position is not 0 in the code, just in the example I extracted just a part of the string. It was a typo.

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem with strpos as I started a needle string with one quote ' and searched for a string that contained double quote ".

Example 1 - Doesn't work:

```
strpos($text,'class="level')
```

Explanation:
  Double quote (") for some reason ends string even if we started string with one quote (').

Example 2 - Doesn't work:

```
strpos($text,'class=\"level')
```

Explanation:
  There is an escape sign before Double quote (") but it doesn't perform it's function.

Example 3 - Works!!:

```
strpos($text,"class=\"level")
```

Explanation:
  If you start needle string with double quote you can then escape double quote with backslash ().

Hope it helps....

Comment: Tks, very helpfull information, you should log a BUG to PHP if there isn't one allready.

Answer (score 0):

why not to `unserialize` this string first?

as for these characters, there is nothing special in them